# How to sort on a dictionary w.r.t the list of values

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have 2 values in the list of each dictionary keys, need to sort the dictionary desc on value1 and asc on value2:

```
dict1={'123126':[100,'DDD'],'123121':[100,'AAA'],'123122':[100,'BBB'],'123123':[101,'CCC']}
dict2 = {key: val for key,val in sorted(dict1.items(), key = lambda ele: ((ele[1][0]),(ele[1][1])), reverse = True)}
print(dict2)

output >>
{'123123': [101, 'CCC'], '123126': [100, 'DDD'], '123122': [100, 'BBB'], '123121': [100, 'AAA']}
```

but the expected output is

```
{'123123': [101, 'CCC'], '123126': [100, 'AAA'], '123122': [100, 'BBB'], '123121': [100, 'DDD']}
```

Comment: I have solved it with two sort seperate statements:

dict1={'123126':[100,'DDD'],'123121':[100,'AAA'],'123122':[100,'BBB'],'123123':[101,'CCC']}
dict2 = {key: val for key,val in sorted(dict1.items(), key = lambda ele: ele[1][1], reverse = False)}
dict3 = {key: val for key,val in sorted(dict2.items(), key = lambda ele: ele[1][0], reverse = True)}

Comment: can you try `dict(sorted(d.items(),key= lambda x:(-x[1][0], x[1][1])))`? I do not understand why my solution does not work on your end.

Comment: Thanks Onyambu.. it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Only invoke the descending. Naturally, sorting is ascending. SO no need to use that. Hence you could do:

```
dict(sorted(d.items(),key= lambda x:-x[1][0]))
Out[25]: 
{'123123': [101, 'CCC'],
 '123126': [100, 'AAA'],
 '123122': [100, 'BBB'],
 '123121': [100, 'DDD']}
```

Comment: This is nt working for me
dict(sorted(dict1.items(),key= lambda x:-x[1][0]))
{'123123': [101, 'CCC'],
 '123126': [100, 'DDD'],
 '123121': [100, 'AAA'],
 '123122': [100, 'BBB']}

Answer (score 0):

I solved using below, though I had hoped this to be done in one statement.

```
dict1={'123126':[100,'DDD'],'123121':[100,'AAA'],'123122':[100,'BBB'],'123123':[101,'CCC']}
dict2 = {key: val for key,val in sorted(dict1.items(), key = lambda ele: ele[1][1], reverse = False)}
dict3 = {key: val for key,val in sorted(dict2.items(), key = lambda ele: ele[1][0], reverse = True)}

print(dict2)
print(dict3)
```

Output

```
{'123121': [100, 'AAA'], '123122': [100, 'BBB'], '123123': [101, 'CCC'], '123126': [100, 'DDD']}
Expeceted- dict3
{'123123': [101, 'CCC'], '123121': [100, 'AAA'], '123122': [100, 'BBB'], '123126': [100, 'DDD']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
This below one solved
dict4 = {key: val for key,val in sorted(dict1.items(), key = lambda ele: (-ele[1][0],ele[1][1]), reverse = False)}